# Early morning on-demand taxi in Basel

Tags: transportation, switzerland, basel

During my journey, I need to go to Basel Airport in the early morning.
I'm looking for popular on-demand taxi service in Basel.

- From: Feldbergstrasse, Basel
- To: Basel Airport
- Time of departure : 6:50AM

Will using a taxi be the best way? Any other idea?

Comment: For the Basel part, you could consider taking a tram. It seems that the first connection will arrive at the airport at 5:39am. (you can check connections [here](http://www.sbb.ch). However, I don't think this is a very good question as it stands. I think you should maybe split this into two question, as the situation in Spain and the situation in Switzerland will be very different.

Comment: @drat okay. i take your advice. I'll split this. thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The majority of the Taxi companies in Basel have a 24h service.

A couple of examples:

- [33er Taxi AG](http://www.33ertaxi.ch)
- [mini-cab](http://www.mini-cab.ch)
- [Taxi-Zentrale](http://www.taxi-zentrale.ch)

Answer (score 8):

Uber POP (aka UberX) is [available in Basel](https://www.uber.com/cities/basel), and estimates CHF 14-18 for the journey.